# multiple variables inside a single span tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, global-variables

I've got the following line:

```
$output .= '<span class="product__price">' . $product->get_price_html() . '</span>';
```

This outputs the price of a Woocommerce product.

I have created a custom Woocommerce field - a label - and I would like to add this label so it shows up just behind this price.

To get my label custom field, I use:

```
$price_label = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_product_price_labels', true );
```

I tried to achieve this by the following string:

```
$output .= '<span class="product__price">' . $product->get_price_html() . '</span><span class="product__price">' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_product_price_labels', true ) . '</span>';
```

So I've got 2 span tags next to each other. It fetches both price and my label, but it places them on the top of each other rather then next to each other like price followed by label.

So ideally, I need to place the second variable string inside the same span tag.

I'm trying this:

```
$output .= '<span class="product__price">' . $product->get_price_html(); get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_product_price_labels', true ) .'</span>';
```

But this won't work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this by using `.` between each string segment or function call!

In your case it would look like this: `$output .= '<span class="product__price">' . $product->get_price_html() . " " . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_product_price_labels', true ) .'</span>';`

Comment: each string already has `.` around it, so how can I join these two strings together using and additional `.` ?

Would you be please able to post the final code as it should look like in your answer?

Comment: That works great, many thanks for your help. 1 last thing. Currently both elements ( price and label) are right next to each other without a space, so it looks like `$120per book` where `$120` is my price element and `per book` is the label element. How do I get a space between the two so it looks like `$120 per book`?